How can I change the value of a var using a checkbox?
I want the value of my variable to change when the checkbox is unchecked. I have it working to when I check the box, the specOrder const is updated but I can't seem to figure out how to remove that value when unchecked.
Here is my code for this section:
const SpecialtyBurgers = () => {

    const [specBurgers, setSpecBurgers] = useState([]);
    useEffect( () => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8800/specialtyburgers')
        .then(res => {
            setSpecBurgers(res.data);
        })
    }, [])

    const [specOrder, setSpecOrder] = useState([]);
    function handleChange(e) {
        if(e.target.checked) 
            setSpecOrder([...specOrder, e.target.value]);
        else if(!e.target.unchecked)
            setSpecOrder([specOrder, ""]);
    }

    var specBurgerDetails = "";
    specBurgerDetails = specBurgers.map( (item, index) => {
        return(
            <div className="item">
                <h2 key={index}>{item.SpecBurgerType}</h2>
                <p>{item.Protein}</p>
                <p>{item.Toppings}</p>
                <p>{item.Price}</p>
                <input type='checkbox' value={item.SpecBurgerType} onChange={handleChange}/>
                <p>{specOrder}</p>
            </div>
        )
    });

As you can see, I tried to use an if statement that either set the value of specBurger to the checkbox value or "". This did not work and it just adds "" to the array. Any ideas?

You are just putting the value back into that array everytime. Even worse, you are adding your array as an item of itself when you uncheck! When unchecked, try removing the value from the array again: specOrder.splice( specOrder.indexOf( e.target.value  ), 1 ). Have a log statement after your if there if you want to know why: soecOrder will go from [ "", "currentValue"] to [[ "", "currentValue"], ""] at the moment. Which will definitely break what you intend to do.

The issue is in your handleChange() function:
    function handleChange(e) {
        if(e.target.checked) 
            setSpecOrder([...specOrder, e.target.value]);
        else if(!e.target.unchecked)
            setSpecOrder([specOrder, ""]);
    }

In your first if section, you're setting the state for specOrder to be the current list of specials (...specOrder) as well as the value of the checked box. That part is working fine. The else if is malformed, however. You need to set the state to the current specOrder but filter out the value of the checked box.
setSpecOrder(specOrder.filter(order => order !== e.target.value))

This will take the list of selected orders, and keep only the orders which don't match the unchecked box.
